# How to display keyboard on the second screen in Dual Screen Android

Tags: android

I have a edittext in the second screen. I want to display keyboard when I click into edittext.

Thanks for your supporting.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a few more details and / or a screenshot of your problem?
- By "dual screen", do you mean "split screen"?
- Are you splitting vertically, or horizontally?
- By default, an on-screen keyboard should automatically pop-up when you focus on an EditText. Is that not happening for you right now?

Comment: the second screen is connect with android device via HDMI cable. So I want to display keyboard on this second screen when I click the view.

Comment: Is your second screen a touchscreen? How do you plan on receiving input from the second screen?

Answer (score 1):

The question makes some incorrect assumptions about external displays on Android. The second screen / external display on Android isn't meant to be an interactive screen, and thus it cannot receive any input (even if the second screen happens to have a touchscreen). Hence, there is no way as of yet in the Android API to show the on-screen keyboard on a secondary display.

There is also the added consideration that the newer Pixel phones do not support second screens via HDMI (which is what you're trying to do), but perhaps that's not relevant for your app.

Comment: Any solution support me to show keyboard on the screen screen?

Comment: @Shams while you say it's not meant to, it certainly can receive touch.